# Seeking to evaluate: $\int_{0}^{1}\arctan(x)\cdot\ln\frac{x+x^3}{(1-x)^2}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

We wish to evaluate this integral,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\arctan(x)\cdot\ln\frac{x+x^3}{(1-x)^2}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$$

I have tried using substitution, $u=\frac{x+x^3}{(1-x)^2}$ and integration by parts but, I am not able to simplify it down.

What can kind of method can we use to evaluate this integral?

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha [says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+arctan+x+ln+x+%2F+x+for+x%3D0..1&dataset=) that $\int_0^1\arctan x\ln x\frac{\mathrm dx}x=-\frac{\pi^3}{32}$, so that's a start, but it can't handle the other two factors.

Comment: Substituting $u=\frac1x$ yields

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\arctan x\ln\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}x
&=&
\int_1^\infty\arctan\frac1x\ln\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}x\;.
\\
&=&
\int_1^\infty\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan x\right)\ln\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}x\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Unfortunately there's a minus sign, so this yields a way of obtaining the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ rather than a way to express the integral from $0$ to $1$ in terms of the integral from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: So

$$
\int_0^\infty\arctan x\ln\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}x=\frac\pi2\int_1^\infty\ln\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}x\;,
$$

which according to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+pi%2F2+ln%28%281%2Bx%5E2%29%2F%281-x%29%5E2%29%2Fx+for+x%3D1..infinity) is $\frac{3\pi^3}{16}$. Not that this is any real progress; I'm just thinking out loud in case any of this happens to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}\ln\left(\frac{x+x^3}{(1-x)^2}\right)dx\\=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln x}{x}dx+\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\right)dx$$

For the first integral, write the taylor series of $\arctan x$

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln x}{x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\int_0^1x^{2n}\ln x\ dx=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=-\beta(3)=-\frac{\pi^3}{32}$$

where [$\beta(3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function?fbclid=IwAR2JKUjyn8sG4wMdUfeT3JyJLpw7C-aanbnwRYbIZ0k9QYwA3Hz1_0OsQhU) is the Dirichlet beta function.

as for the second one, it is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3204668)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\right)dx=\frac{\pi^3}{16}$$

$$\Longrightarrow I=\frac{\pi^3}{32}$$

Comment: Why is the first integral trivial?

Comment: Just write the Taylor series of $\arctan x$ and see what you get. I can write the details if you like.

Comment: Thanks. I can substitute the Taylor series and perform the integral, but I don't know how to evaluate the resulting sum $\sum_k(-1)^k/(2k+1)^3$. I found it evaluated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581146), but I wouldn't exactly call that trivial :-) Is there an easier way to evaluate this sum?

Comment: What's left is the dirichlet beta function $\beta(3)$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function

Comment: Aha, thanks a lot, good to know :-)

Comment: You welcome. $\beta(3)$ can be calculated differently but I didnt as it's already a well known value.

Comment: @joriki more like is trivial in comparison to the other integral, since that one is quite difficult. For a way to find that sum, notice that: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi} {2} \right)} {n^3}$$ And integrate twice the fourier series of $\frac{\pi-x} {2} $, similarly as seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3285129/515527

Comment: @Zacky: Thanks, that makes it more accessible to me :-)